# Is there any way to access laravel model dynamically through variable when model name is stored in variable?

Tags: php, laravel

Basically what I need to do is:

```
$x = 'Admin';
$model = new \ReflectionClass($x);
$model->getFieldList();
```

Where I have Admin model inside app folder.
Obviously, this doesn't work. Does anyone have any idea? Can it be done?

Comment: What isn't working? Do you get an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this, but you need to use the fully qualified class name.for example My models are in the `Model` directory :

```
$model = 'App\Model\User';
$user=$model::where('id', $id)->first();
```

Answer (score 6):

Firstly you need to add the namespace to your model. By default this is `App\`. So your string would have to be `"\App\Admin"`. Now you can simply create a class instance using this string.

```
$x = '\\App\\Admin';
$model = new $x();
```

Answer (score 0):

i use something like that in the controller constructor. here what i use:

1)first declare a variable in parent controller lets say:
$route_model_name and $model_location.

2. then add this to each child controller:

   ```
   function __construct() {
     parent::__construct();
     $this->setRouteModelName( 'model_route_name' );
     $this->setModelLocation( 'App\Models\ModelName' );
   }
   ```
3. then you add a method in the parent controller to initialize the model class in order to be ready for making queries:

   ```
    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function getModelClass() {
        return app( $this->model_class );
    }
   ```
4. then you can change the model location and route in each of the child controllers and still use the same method in the parent controller:

   ```
    public function edit( $id ) {
        return $this->getModelClass()::where( 'id', $id )->first();
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
$model = 'App?Models?'.$model;
$model = str_replace('?','\\',$model);

return $model::products()->paginate();
```